# Show extra fields in registration form just for one customer group

Tags: customer, forms, register

I have dropdown selector in my registration form, for choose in which customer group customers want register.
This is my code for dropdow:

```
   <form action="register.phtml" method="post"> 
    <div class="input-box">
        <label for="group_id"><?php echo $this->__('Odaberite razinu') ?><span class="required">*</span></label><br/>
        <select name="group_id" id="group_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Group') ?>" class="validate-group required-entry input-text" />
            <?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
            <?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
            <option value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['value'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
   </form>
```

Now I want show some extra fields in reg. form just for customer group with ID 4. I try something like this, but nothing happens. Extra fields don't show up when group with ID 4 is selected:

```
    <?php 

        if ( $_POST['group_id'] == '4')
        {
    ?>

            <my html code with extra fields>

             ?>
```

How I can check what customer group is selected and besides on that show some extra html fields for customer to insert?
Is it my "if" correct and something is wrong or I something missing up in dropdown form?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for your issue?

Comment: yes I did. please see my answer below. thank you for your answer and suggestion to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The `_POST` variable is not filled until an actual post is done. I think you are looking for a dynamic javascript solution in this case.

I'm no javascript or prototype expert so please double check this Javascript but I think you're looking for something along the lines of this

```
<select name="group_id" id="group_id" ... >
   [...]
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="group_specific_attr" id="group_specific_attr" class="" value=""/>

<script>
$('group_id').observer('change', function(){
   if ($(this).value == 4)
   {
      $('group_id').setAttribute('type','text');
      $('group_id').setAttribute('class','required-entry');
   }
   else
   {
      $('group_id').setAttribute('type','hidden');
      $('group_id').setAttribute('class','');
   }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for that issue. Hope someone helps. 
I use simple javascript function:

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
             function izborgrupe(type)
                {
                   document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
                   document.getElementById(type).style.display = "";
                }
         </script>
```

Before that in select tag use "onchange" to call function above:

```
<select name="group_id" id="group_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('Group') ?>" class="validate-group required-entry input-text" onchange="izborgrupe(this.value)">
                    <?php $groups = Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray(); ?>
                    <?php foreach($groups as $group){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php print $group['value'] ?>"><?php print $group['label'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

And at the end I named span tag where is my extra filed with ID 4 and give style to display:none

```
    <span id="4" style="display:none">  

         <div class="fieldset">
            <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="school" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Broj osnovnog osiguranja') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="school" id="school" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getSchool()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('school') ?>" class="input-text" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </span>
```

As result, extra field from span ID "4" will shows up only when value "4" from dropdown is selected.